# MacOS app on Big Sur with java child process and accessibility API privilege

Tags: java, macos, macos-big-sur

We have a MacOS app that uses a .command file to start a java application

`java -jar some.jar`

That application has access to accessibility API (configured in "System Preferences" > "Security & Privacy" > "Accessibility").

Now at some point this java application starts a java child process with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)`

Why doesn't this child process inherit the privilige for accessibility?

edit: removed false statement about catalina

Comment: I'm using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)` on Catalina and I'm getting no problems about privileges. Anyway, it depends on privileges. If you're running your program under `$USER` you should check what privileges that command requires: if it requires root or not. It's a little bit generic the question.

Comment: @Virgula I'm specifically asking about the privilege to access the Accessbility API. The app package that runs the java process is allowed to access it. But the java process I spawn isn't.

Comment: Hi  @Reinhold. I'm facing something very similar and was just wondering if you found a solution to this issue.
Any help will be appreciated.